# Returning the kth of multiple matches

Tags: excel, excel-2011

In Excel for Mac 2011, I am trying to create a table (in columns `D-G`) that references the data in `A1:B5`. I want `E1` to search column `A` and report the data in column `B` corresponding to the first match; `F1` to search column `A` and report the second match; `G1` the third match, etc. `VLOOKUP` would solve the problem for `E1`, but to my knowledge can't handle anything past the first match.

Here is the formula I have found in other help sites:

`=INDEX($B$1:$B$5,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$5=$D$1,ROW($A$1:$A$5)-MIN(ROW($A$1:$A$5))+1,""),COLUMN(A1)))`

This works perfectly for `E1`, but results in a `#NUM!` error in cell `F1`. I entered the following formula into another cell and got a value of `1`, which led me to believe that my formula is only finding one match:

`=MAX((IF($A$1:$A$5=$D$1,ROW($A$1:$A$5)-MIN(ROW($A$1:$A$5))+1,"")))`

I can't figure out where the first formula is going wrong. If anyone has any ideas, or other ways to do this, that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify like:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$5;SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$5=$D$1;ROW($A$1:$A$5)-MIN(ROW($A$1:$A$5))+1;"");2))
```

intead of COLUMN(A1) you need to put the number of **kth** element.
you have a **NUM#** if there isn't the **kth** position in the array...
In that case you need to use a:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$5;SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$5=$D$1;ROW($A$1:$A$5)-MIN(ROW($A$1:$A$5))+1;"");2));"")
```

Obviusly the formula shell be inserted with CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately it still isn't working. I am getting the NUM# error for k=2 even if there are multiple matches in the data. Is there anything wrong in the formula that should cause this issue?